# How do you run a codeception test from within a php script?

Tags: php, testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

I do **not** want to run a codeception test from the CLI:

```
php <pathToCodeCeption>/codecept run
```

I want to run it inside a PHP script:

```
<?php

$codeCeptionRunner = /* What to do here*/;
$codeCeptionRunner->run();
```

Does anyone has an idea how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with this snippet:

```
<?php
require_once '/path/to/codeception/autoload.php';

$Codecept = new \Codeception\Codecept(array(
    'steps' => true,
    'verbosity' => 1,
    // some other options (see Codeception docs/sources)
 ));

 $Codecept->run('your_test_suit_name');
```

and then dig into Codeception sources. It is really clear and easy to understand.

Comment: Could you please let me know in detail. I have run the above script, it work's perfect for me. But I want to know in detail.  I am not able to find the docs/sources folder in codeception.

Comment: @PayalPandav I think it's kinda offtopic here, but I would try to answer. Codeception sources are hosted on github: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception, docs can be found there in docs folder or online https://codeception.com/docs/

Comment: I have checked whole documentation but I didn't get the PHP script with an object.    $Codecept->run('your_test_suit_name');   I required the HTML report and all other option of Codecept object.
I have tried the                                                                                  
                                                                                                         $Codecept = new \Codeception\Codecept(array(
        'steps' => true,
       'verbosity' => 1,
       'html' => true,
 ));   but not work for me. Can you please do needfull for me. Thank you